# Android Google+ login doesn't work - statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to let the user login with Google+. I have created the project in the Google developer console, I got the Client ID and I have installed the Google play services in Android Studio. (My running device has Android 4.4.2)
When the app is running and I press the login button a toast message appears: 
"Internal Error"

The error in the Logcat is the following:

```
error ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{429ffe38: android.os.BinderProxy@429ffdd8}}
```

Notice that this error appears before that the user has pressed the button, in fact, through debugging, I figured out it comes from this line code:

```
Log.e(TAG, "error " + result.toString());
```

which is in the method:

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mGoogleIntentInProgress) {
        /* Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks on the Google+ login button */
        mGoogleConnectionResult = result;

        if (mGoogleLoginClicked) {
            /* The user has already clicked login so we attempt to resolve all errors until the user is signed in,
             * or they cancel. */
            resolveSignInError();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "error " + result.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here the other important methods:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    SignInButton googleLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_with_google);
    googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mGoogleLoginClicked = true;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                if (mGoogleConnectionResult != null) {
                    resolveSignInError();
                } else if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin();
                } else {
                /* connect API now */
                    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to connect to Google API");
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

    });

    /* Setup the Google API object to allow Google+ logins */
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
}

 private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mGoogleConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mGoogleIntentInProgress = true;
            mGoogleConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
            mGoogleIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
        /* This was a request by the Google API */
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleLoginClicked = false;
        }
        mGoogleIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


}
```

Here the code in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And the meta-data

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope you can help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe Google are having issues with login at the moment.  Their OAuth login provider keeps returning access_denied.  It's been driving me crazy for the past 30 minutes - quick look on Twitter and it seems to be an issue on Google's end.

Answer (score 6):

As in my project, there are many problems with Google+ sign in. Example, when create `mGoogleApiClient`, you should

```
           mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) 
                .addApi(Plus.API) 
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) 
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE) 
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this) 
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) 
                .build();
```

with `SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE`   - OAuth 2.0 scope for accessing the user's Google+ profile data.

You need to enable Google+ API and create Credentials with SHA1 and your package.

OAuth Consent screen with your **email** and **product name**  (required)

More, make sure: 

**applicationId** in tag <application> 
**package name** in AndroidManifest.xml 
**package name** in Credentials in Google Developer Console

**all same**

More, make sure you have the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

More, in method 
    `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data {
    ...
    ...
    }`

**DO NOT** need call **super.onActivityResult**(requestCode, resultCode, data);

And more thing also important: **debug keystore** and **release keystore**.

And more .....

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your action, if you don't really need to be signed, you can keep the connection open.

Replace

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

with

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect(2); // SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL = 2
```