# Android app authentication with Firebase as the backend Error: statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, firebase, google-signin

I've been working on setting up Google+ Sign-in for my Android app. The backend is set up on Firebase with my web application's client ID and secret but it throws the following run-time error after trying to login with a Google account on Android Studio:

ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{3a466ee7: android.os.BinderProxy@2586e4da}, message=null}

Below are some important snippets of my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mGoogleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mGoogleLoginClicked = true;
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    if (mGoogleConnectionResult != null) {
                        resolveSignInError();
                    } else if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin();
                    } else {
                    /* connect API now */
                        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to connect to Google API");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        /* Setup the Google API object to allow Google+ logins */
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://boiling-heat-5858.firebaseio.com");

        mAuthProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuthProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        mAuthProgressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating with Firebase...");
        mAuthProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mAuthProgressDialog.show();

        mAuthStateListener = new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
            private TextView mLoggedInStatusTextView;

            private void setAuthenticatedUser(AuthData authData) {
                mGoogleLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String name = null;

                if (name != null) {
                    mLoggedInStatusTextView.setText("Logged in as " + name + " (" + authData.getProvider() + ")");
                }
             else {
                mGoogleLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }}

            public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
                mAuthProgressDialog.hide();
            }
        };
        /* Check if the user is authenticated with Firebase already. If this is the case we can set the authenticated
         * user and hide hide any login buttons */
        mFirebaseRef.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();

        mGoogleLoginClicked = true;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            if (mGoogleConnectionResult != null) {
                resolveSignInError();
            } else if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin();
            } else {
                    /* connect API now */
                Log.d(TAG, "Trying to connect to Google API");
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin() {
        /* Get OAuth token in Background */
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            String errorMessage = null;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String token = null;

                try {
                    String scope = String.format("oauth2:%s", Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(OAuth.this, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), scope);
                } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                    /* Network or server error */
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error authenticating with Google: " + transientEx);
                    errorMessage = "Network error: " + transientEx.getMessage();
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Recoverable Google OAuth error: " + e.toString());
                    /* We probably need to ask for permissions, so start the intent if there is none pending */
                    if (!mGoogleIntentInProgress) {
                        mGoogleIntentInProgress = true;
                        Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                        startActivityForResult(recover, OAuth.RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
                    }
                } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                    /* The call is not ever expected to succeed assuming you have already verified that
                     * Google Play services is installed. */
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error authenticating with Google: " + authEx.getMessage(), authEx);
                    errorMessage = "Error authenticating with Google: " + authEx.getMessage();
                }

                return token;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                mGoogleLoginClicked = false;
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                if (token != null) {
                    mFirebaseRef.authWithOAuthToken("google", token, new AuthResultHandler("google"));
                } /*else if (errorMessage != null) {
                  //  rmAuthProgressDialog.hide();
                    //showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
                }*/
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

I have spent hours on researching and trying out all of the existing threads on the subject, but nothing has helped me so far. Hoping for someone to be able to point out what am I missing.

Comment: Did you add the relevant permissions to the manifest? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882356/android-google-login-doesnt-work-statuscode-sign-in-required

Comment: Also: you code looks like it targets an older version of Google Play Services. While that should work, consider updating to the latest version. In that case, you could do worse than using this sign-in code from the FirebaseUI library as your inspiration: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/google/GoogleAuthProvider.java